# Sharing Image to social media

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Did anyone know how to share image + link to social media? (example facebook).
I already try to share link and it works, but i cant find the way to share the full image.

Comment: How is this a programming related question?

Comment: yes this is programming question

Comment: Then please give us some code of your progress or something.  It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about the image share on facebook? If so, you need to link the image with meta tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/lamb-full.jpg">
```

more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object